# Security error accessing url

Tags: apache-flex, jetty

I have issue an one of my flex based application running on jetty server. my application will call the webservice running on the same web server. I can access my application using localhost but when i am trying to access my application other than localhost (public ip or private ip) it throws "SECURITY ERROR ACCESSING URL"

Aslo I tried with crossdomain.xml but no effect.

please suggest any fix to solve this issue.

Comment: please post the crossdomain.xml file and your code(relevant to the error) and the error

Comment: <!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "http://www.macromedia.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">
<cross-domain-policy>
 <site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="all" />
 <allow-access-from domain="*" secure="false" />
 <allow-http-request-headers-from domain="*" headers="*" secure="false" />
 <allow-https-request-headers-from domain="*" headers="*"/>
</cross-domain-policy>

Comment: This is my crossdomain.xml

Comment: edit your question and place your code and xml there, use the code tags